# How to write LINQ to SQL query for getting today date records?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I want to get the today entered records using LINQ to SQL. I wrote the below code but it is returning previous date records also.

```
DateTime todaysDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime yesterdaysDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

var result = (from a in cxt.visitor.OrderByDescending(n => n.singin)
              where (a.singin > yesterdaysDate && a.singin <= todaysDate)
              select new {a.visitorid, a.visitorname, a.visitingperson, a.phonenumber, a.reasonforvisit, a.signature, a.singin });
```

Can you please tell me how to get the today entered records only using LINQ to SQL?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Insetad of `DateTime.Now` use `DateTime.Today` like:

```
DateTime startDateTime = DateTime.Today; //Today at 00:00:00
DateTime endDateTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1); //Today at 23:59:59

var result = (from a in cxt.visitor.OrderByDescending(n => n.singin)
            where (a.singin >= startDateTime && a.singin <= endDateTime)
            select new {a.visitorid, a.visitorname, a.visitingperson, a.phonenumber, a.reasonforvisit, a.signature, a.singin });
```

or You can try the following simpler version, *(I am not sure if that would translate into SQL)*

```
var result = (from a in cxt.visitor.OrderByDescending(n => n.singin)
            where (a.singin.Date == DateTime.Today)
            select new {a.visitorid, a.visitorname, a.visitingperson, a.phonenumber, a.reasonforvisit, a.signature, a.singin });
```

Comment: Is'nt the `DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1)` and `<= endDateTime` a bit overcomplicated? `DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)` and `< endDateTime` would have achieved the same thing, wouldn't it?

Comment: I definitely meant `<= endDateTime`. I was referring to the fact that by using `.AddTicks(-1)` it means you need a `<=` comparison, when you can just leave it out and use `<`. It doesn't really matter, your answer is still correct. :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the second simpler version **cannot** translate into SQL